# React Redux form submit not giving right results

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to implement a form submit with react and redux. When i submit the data here, i want to get the results in actions (for redux purposes). I know we can do this by giving 'ref' in each input tags. but what i want to do it in react-redux method.

[demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n4uaii?embed=1&file=actions/AddMovieActions.js)

You can console and see the results obtaining as objects. but I'm not getting the right results.

Comment: what you can do is pass a handleSubmit props. and on that call your reducer. `handleSubmit(data) { dispatch({ type: 'whatever', payload: data }) }` easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issue is that you are using `<input` element with redux-form.

I recommend using `<Field name="title" component="input" type="text" />` instead.

1. Include it `import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'`
2. `<Field name="title" component="input" type="text" />`
3. `console.log("i want the results right here ",form.movieForm.values.title);`

Please NOTE: Its highly recommended to create a function within your component file which captures the input values and then calls the `dispatch` action creator